# batch test code passes, but scheduled batch does not

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, scheduled-apex

My batch code it my test class passes the assert. But when I run the scheduled batch that runs the same batch code, it fails. Shouldn't a scheduled class that runs a batch pass the same assert as running the batch class on its own?

```
@isTest
private class ReportHistoricOfferListingBatchTest {

    @testSetup
    static void setup() {
       // to keep this post short, I deleted the setup data code
    }

    static testmethod void test() { 
        String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0 15 3 ? 2022';

        Test.startTest(); 
        // this line of code passes the assert when uncommented
        //Database.executeBatch(new ReportHistoricOfferListingBatch());

        // this line below does not pass the assert
        System.schedule('ScheduledApexTest', CRON_EXP, new ReportHistoricOfferListingBatchSchedule());
        Test.stopTest();

        System.assertEquals([SELECT Id FROM pba__Offer__c WHERE Final_Bid_Up_Amount__c = 10].Id, [SELECT Reporting_Current_Offer_Historic__c FROM pba__Listing__c].Reporting_Current_Offer_Historic__c);
    }

}
```

The schedule class:

```
global class ReportHistoricOfferListingBatchSchedule implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        Database.executeBatch(new ReportHistoricOfferListingBatch());
    }
}
```

Comment: note you can combine both the schedulable class and batchable class into one class with `implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<Sobject>`. You can also make them public, instead of global (unless you are building a managed package)

Comment: that's awesome. Make sense. Nice way to refactor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're testing the schedule, you just want to query the `AsyncApexJob`. You have an asynchronous function kicking off an asynchronous function, only the former executes when you hit `Test.stopTest()`.

```
Test.startTest();
    // schedule job
Test.stopTest();
// now your scheduled job has executed
// that kicks off the batch, which is just now starting to run

Integer executedJobs = [
    SELECT count() FROM AsyncApexJob
    WHERE JobType = 'BatchApex'
    AND ApexClass.Name = 'BatchClassName'
];
system.assertEquals(1, executedJobs, 'The job should be scheduled');
```

Comment: so the whole point of a test for a scheduled test class is to assert that it was scheduled, not to assert that the functionality of the code being scheduled executed?

Comment: If you want to test the batch, do so directly. You can also check executing the schedule runs the batch by calling the `execute` method directly: `new MySchedulable().execute(null)`.